# Running total on an array of numbers classic asp

Tags: arrays, asp-classic

I have an array a=Array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)

I need to add 1+2+3 then 2+3+4 then 3+4+5 and so on until 8+9+10

Or in other words first item plus second item plus third item then second item plus third item plus fourth item and so on

How can I do it in classic asp, here is my attempt. or one of the attempts.

```
            Dim p, m, a, t
            a = array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,12,13,14)
            t = 0
            p = 0    
            m = 0       
            For x = m To 14                                    
                p = p + 1                    
                if p < 4 then
                    t = t + a(x)
                end if
                if p = 3 then
                    m = 0
                    p = 0
                    ReDim Preserve arr(UBound(a) - 1)
                    response.Write t & "<br />"
                end if
            Next
```

My plan was to add 4 items, then reset the starting index when it hit the 4th item (that is m = 0) and at this point also get rid of the first item from the array so when it starts again the second item becomes the first item.

Comment: This isn't rent-a-coder, we are not here to write the solution for you. Please supply a [mcve] showing your attempt at solving the problem and we will go from there.

Comment: I have added more information, I hope it helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're making things more complicated than they need to be. (Either that, or you've oversimplified the question in an effort to remove the identifying details.)

```
For i = 0 to UBound(a) - 2
    t = a(i) + a(i+1) + a(i+2)
    Response.Write a(i) & " + " & a(i+1) & " + " & a(i+2) & " = " & t & "<br>"
Next
```

Comment: Martha you are a super star. You gave me just the thing I wanted. As you can see from my code I am not that a good programmer. but you made it so simple.

Thanks alot